# Hibernate Search with nGram | How to instruct that nGram do no make grams during search time

Tags: elasticsearch, hibernate-search

I have defined my Analyzer as below

```
@AnalyzerDefs({
@AnalyzerDef(name = "ngram",
            tokenizer = @TokenizerDef(factory = KeywordTokenizerFactory.class),
            filters = {
                    //@TokenFilterDef(factory = StandardFilterFactory.class),
                    @TokenFilterDef(factory = LowerCaseFilterFactory.class),
                    @TokenFilterDef(factory = NGramFilterFactory.class, params = {
                            @Parameter(name = "minGramSize", value = "3"),
                            @Parameter(name = "maxGramSize", value = "255") }) }),
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------
    @AnalyzerDef(name = "ngram_query",
            tokenizer = @TokenizerDef(factory = KeywordTokenizerFactory.class),
            filters = {
                    //@TokenFilterDef(factory = StandardFilterFactory.class),
                    @TokenFilterDef(factory = LowerCaseFilterFactory.class)
                    }) 
})

@Analyzer(definition = "ngram")
public class EPCAsset extends Asset {
    @Field
    private String obturatorMaterial;

}
```

It perfectly makes n-grams term vectors during index time. But it also makes n-gram of search query during search time.

What i want is a way by which search query uses n-gram index to search without breaking the search term into grams.

Note: I have to use n-gram here because the requirement is to search anywhere in the text. either start or in middle. so edge-n-gram is not an option for me.

Example:
Input Data to be index **ICQ 234**

Then during index time its term vectors are

> ```
>     "234"
>     " 23"
>     " 234"
>     "cq "
>     "cq 2"
>     "cq 23"
>     "cq 234"
>     "icq"
>     "icq "
>     "icq 2"
>     "icq 23"
>     "icq 234"
>     "q 2"
>     "q 23"
>     "q 234"
> ```

Now when I search **icq** it works perfectly. But it also works for **icqabc** As during search time it makes n-grams of search query. So is there a way that during search time it do not break the search term but use n-gram index for searching.

Here is my search query building

```
FullTextEntityManager fullTextEntityManager = Search
            .getFullTextEntityManager(entityManager);

QueryBuilder qb = fullTextEntityManager.getSearchFactory().buildQueryBuilder()
            .forEntity(entityClass).get();
Query query = qb.phrase().onField("obturatorMaterial").sentence("icqabc").createQuery();
FullTextQuery fullTextQuery = fullTextEntityManager.createFullTextQuery(query,
            entityClass);
fullTextQuery.getResultList()
```

I am using elastic search as backend for Hibernate search.

**EDIT:**
I also has applied query time analyzer as per @yrodiere's answer but it give me error.

```
QueryBuilder qb = fullTextEntityManager.getSearchFactory().buildQueryBuilder()
            .forEntity(entityClass).overridesForField("obturatorMaterial","ngram_query").get();
```

> org.hibernate.search.exception.SearchException: HSEARCH000353: Unknown analyzer: 'ngram_query'. Make sure you defined this analyzer.

**EDIT**

As per this link [overriderForField when using elasticsearch backed hibernate search](https://discourse.hibernate.org/t/cannot-find-the-overridden-analyzer-when-using-overridesforfield/1043)

I am now able to define a query time 2nd analyzer and it solved the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should double check that an ngram filter really is what you want. I'm mentioning this because the ngram analyzer is generally used both at indexing and querying, so that it provides fuzzy matches. It's kind of the whole point of this analyzer.

Do you really need matches when the user types `cq 2`? Does it make sense? When implementing autocomplete, people generally prefer to only match documents containing words that *start* with the user input, so `i` would match, `ic` and `icq` would too, but not `cq 2`. If this seems to be what you want, you should have a look at the "edge_ngram" filter. It tends to improve the relevance of matches and also doesn't require as much disk space.

Now, even with the "edge_ngram" filter you will need to disable ngrams at query time. In Hibernate Search, this is done by "overriding" the analyzer.

1. First, define a second analyzer, identical to the one you use during indexing, but without the "ngram" or "edge_ngram" filter. Name it "ngram_query".
2. Then, use this to create your query builder:

   ```
   QueryBuilder queryBuilder = fullTextEntityManager.getSearchFactory().buildQueryBuilder().forEntity(EPCAsset.class)
       .overridesForField( "obturatorMaterial", "ngram_query" )
       .get();
   ```
3. Use the query builder to create your query as usual.

Note that, if you rely on Hibernate Search to push the index schema and analyzers to Elasticsearch, you will have to use a hack in order for the query-only analyzer to be pushed: by default only the analyzers that are actually used during indexing are pushed. See https://discourse.hibernate.org/t/cannot-find-the-overridden-analyzer-when-using-overridesforfield/1043/4

Comment: Hi yrodiere , As per your concern about searching cq 2 Yes it does not make sense. but that is what our client wanted. client wants to search in middle of any sentence. e.g. "A quick brown fox jumps" and if he writes own instead of brown then he wants to see all relevant occurrence. But anyway thanks for pointing me to right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Either you need to use [search time analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-analyzer.html) and very likely it would be the keyword analyzer during search time. Or need to use `term` query instead of `match` query, which is analyzed means it uses the same analyzer used index time.

Read more about [term query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-term-query.html) and [match query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/match-query.html) for more information.

**Edit** :- https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-analyzer.html clearly talked about the use of **search_analyzer**, in case of **edgeNGram tokenizer** and **autocomplete search** which is exactly your use case.